# Position of “etwas” in “Kann ich in Berlin etwas kaufen?”

Tags: word-order, adverb

So I learned about TMP (time, manner, place) in order to correctly position my adverbs, and then went through Pimsleur I.

However, I came across a sentence that annoys me because it didn’t follow what I had learned. It was:

> Kann ich in Berlin etwas kaufen?

But I feel like I should say:

> Kann ich etwas in Berlin kaufen?

As far as I understand, *etwas* is a pronoun, and those usually come before location. So why is it flipped? Is it because it was a question? I’m confused.

Comment: Für mich sind beide Sätze in Ordnung. IMHO ist im ersten Satz _in Berlin_ ein wenig stärker betont und im zweiten _etwas_.

Comment: If there is anything to add to Wrzlprmft's answer it is: TMP or whichever other rule you heard is like the Pirates' Code as set down by Morgan and Bartholomew. And the code is more what you'd call *guidelines* than actual rules. Welcome to German language's Black Pearl!

Comment: TMP is a guideline that coveres probably half of all sentences. The other half is NOT TMP but MTP and PTM and TPM and PMT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both word orders are correct and only slightly differ in emphasis: Whatever you put first **in this case**, is slightly more focussed by the question (at least that’s my impression, even native speakers can disagree over this). Some examples in context:

> Ich kann in Hamburg, München und Köln einen Hut kaufen. Aber: Kann ich in Berlin einen Hut kaufen? [emphasis on *Berlin*]
>
> Ich kann Schuhe, Krawatten und Röcke in Berlin kaufen. Aber: Kann ich einen Hut in Berlin kaufen? [emphasis on *Hut*]

If you do not want to emphasise either, both word orders are correct. This has nothing to do with the sentence being a question. However, if the sentence weren’t a question, you could put whatever you like to emphasise to the very front:

> In Hamburg, München und Köln kann ich keinen Hut kaufen. In Berlin kann ich es.
>   [*es* replaces *einen Hut kaufen* to avoid repetition.]

I do not see, how TMP plays into this, as *etwas* is the object in your sentence and not an adverbial. (However, I am no expert on such rules, as I am a native speaker.) But even when talking about adverbials, it’s correct to swap their orders for emphasis. For example you all permutations of the following are correct, as long as *einen Hut* comes after *heute* or directly after *ich* (though this restrictions seems to only apply to me – see the comments):

> Kann ich [in Berlin] [heute] [einen Hut] [mit Dir] kaufen?

So the following are correct (all with slightly different emphasis):

> Kann ich in Berlin heute einen Hut mit Dir kaufen?
>   Kann ich in Berlin heute mit Dir einen Hut kaufen?
>   Kann ich in Berlin mit Dir heute einen Hut kaufen?
>   Kann ich heute in Berlin einen Hut mit Dir kaufen?
>   Kann ich heute in Berlin mit Dir einen Hut kaufen?
>   Kann ich heute einen Hut in Berlin mit Dir kaufen?
>   Kann ich heute einen Hut mit Dir in Berlin kaufen?
>   Kann ich heute mit Dir in Berlin einen Hut kaufen?
>   Kann ich heute mit Dir einen Hut in Berlin kaufen?
>   Kann ich einen Hut in Berlin heute mit Dir kaufen?
>   Kann ich einen Hut in Berlin mit Dir heute kaufen?
>   Kann ich einen Hut heute in Berlin mit Dir kaufen?
>   Kann ich einen Hut heute mit Dir in Berlin kaufen?
>   Kann ich einen Hut mit Dir in Berlin heute kaufen?
>   Kann ich einen Hut mit Dir heute in Berlin kaufen?
>   Kann ich mit Dir in Berlin heute einen Hut kaufen?
>   Kann ich mit Dir heute in Berlin einen Hut kaufen?
>   Kann ich mit Dir heute einen Hut in Berlin kaufen?

And incorrect are (to me):

> Kann ich in Berlin mit Dir einen Hut heute kaufen?
>   Kann ich in Berlin einen Hut mit Dir heute kaufen?
>   Kann ich in Berlin einen Hut heute mit Dir kaufen?
>   Kann ich mit Dir in Berlin einen Hut heute kaufen?
>   Kann ich mit Dir einen Hut in Berlin heute kaufen?
>   Kann ich mit Dir einen Hut heute in Berlin kaufen?

TMP is more a guideline on how to position components, when you do not want to put a special emphasis on something. from the above the following order is perceived as rather neutral with respect to emphasis:

> Kann ich heute mit Dir in Berlin einen Hut kaufen?

Putting the object *(einen Hut)* in front would emphasise it, though I cannot attribute this to a particular rule.

Note, that while in all the above examples, something was emphasised by putting by putting it earlier in the sentence, this is mostly a coincidence and what is more important is the deviation from the “neutral” order. For example in the following sentence, *einen Hut* and *heute* are emphasised:

> Kann ich einen Hut mit Dir in Berlin heute kaufen?

Also, in most cases, spoken epmhasis overrides emphasis by word order.

Comment: I don't completely agree with the notes on emphasis; while in "Kann ich in Berlin einen Hut kaufen?", the emphasis could lie on either Berlin or the hat, in "Kann ich einen Hut in Berlin kaufen?", the emphasis seems to be definitely on Berlin. "Ich kann in Hamburg, München und Köln einen Hut kaufen. Aber: Kann ich einen Hut in Berlin kaufen?" As we already know we're talking about the hat, that is placed in the beginning, along with the other not so interesting parts of the sentence; the crucial modification, Berlin, that we're actually inquiring about, is placed near the question mark.

Comment: I agree with @O.R.Mapper... it is difficult to read these sentence in a neutral way and not have the inflection override what's there but usually the later the element the more crucial. The earlier elements are usually the protagonists of the sentence and stuff we already know. The jargon term is "Rhema" and "THema". The emphasis created by word order is not very strong in this case so you just have to raise your voice a little at "Hut" and you've masked it, but it's there. For a scientific treatment check the Dudengrammatik, for a "Bild"-Zeitung version you can check out my blog

Comment: https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/german-word-order/

Comment: @Emanuel: Fascinating - after reading so often that in German, whatever comes first is most emphasized, and always feeling this does not completely reflect what the language actually works like (I'm a native speaker), your blog, in particular the explanation "The more unusual a spot is for a box, the more tension is created because we’re going against the natural tendencies there are." exactly nails it. Very relieving to know that my own impression of emphasis is shared by others rather than completely twisted.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I do not share your evaluation of the emphasis in “Kann ich [in Berlin] [einen Hut] kaufen?”, but I admit that the emphasis is very slight. I would rather say that in written language the question is mainly marked by the inverted word order and thus everything placed more close to *kann ich* is emphasised. (In spoken language, you would use vocal emphasis anyway.) Anyaway, I amended the answer as to alleviate my statement about the emphasis in this particular sentence.

Comment: @Emanuel: I only noticed through the comments that in all examples in my answer emphasis lied on the earlier components. I amended my answer to clarify that this is coincidental and added a little bit about emphasis in general.

Comment: I would generally say „Kann ich in Berlin einen Hut kaufen?“, but „Kann ich den Hut in Berlin kaufen?“. The example with „etwas“ is more like the first one, for example „das“ would be like the second one.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... that's because of the "thema-rhema" thing. "Der Hut" and "das" are used when the element has already been established. The hat has been the subject of the conversation and where we can buy it is the new information, the "Rhema". "Ein Hut" however is a new character and since it is the direct object it is most defining for the verb "kaufen" so it is further to the right.

Comment: @Emanuel, I had not seen your comment and above and never heard of *rhema*, but that seems exactly right to me and a much better way to look at it than *emphasis*.

Comment: Just in case anyone wonders... in English linguistics "Thema-Rhema" is "topic-comment"  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic–comment

Comment: @Emanuel So I read that article on word order. Thanks. I also left a question in the comment on the 3rd part :) took me like 4 hours to read all that

Comment: @Autumn... yeah, the whole mini series is somewhat of a read... but I hope that on the long run it was worth it :) (I answered your comment, too)

Comment: "And incorrect are:" Actually those all make sense to me (native speaker). They sure are clunky, but with some emphasis on different words they still make sense. Is there actually a written rule somewhere that forbids these word orders?

Comment: @jmiserez.. oh wow, I didn't see these. I totally agree. They are NOT incorrect. They linguistic term is that they are highly marked. However, in theory there might be a context where anything but "heute" is already known so the speaker wants to know whether he can buy a hat with me in Berlin TODAY... as opposed to other days. In such a context the last sentence would be valid. Calling them incorrect implies that there is something about the order itself that doesn't work when in fact it's only the lack of a fitting context that makes 'em sound odd. Also...

Comment: swap "einen Hut" for "den Hut" and the situation changes and "Kann ich mit dir den Hut heute in Berlin kaufen" is much less clunky, for example.

Comment: @Emanuel: I disagree on these, though I cannot back it up right now. These word-orders are not highly marked to me, they are just wrong.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... well, then you should insert a little "to me" in there or say that it SOUNDS wrong, because when you say that it's incorrect then you're saying there's a rule that has been broken. And there is no such rule. A sentence with the same basic constituents but a different verb may well sound correct. What you're doing by claiming that it's incorrect is you're misleading the students. They will try to figure out why it's incorrect. If it sounds wrong to you then that's how it is but for other native speakers it is not "wrong"

Comment: To further my point, here's an example: "Kann ich mit dir den Film dort am Freitag sehen?"... same order of constituents as the last "incorrect" one and yet it is totally fine. Now how do you want to explain that to a student? I mean, other than saying "it depens on the sentence itself"

Comment: @Emanuel: I edited the anwser. Your example does not convince me either though, and has the disadvantage that *dort* can be directly related to *den Film,* as in *that DVD over there.* But the sentence does not work for me either, if you replace *dort* with *im Kino.*

Comment: **This post was flagged to be moved to chat for having too many comments. Please avoid lengthy comment discussions. If an issue was resolved you should delete your comment. For an elaborate discussions on a topic use [chat].**

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct, but the emphasis is different, as pointed out by Wrzlprmft. The result is that to me, at least, the two questions are quite different.

> Kann ich in Berlin etwas kaufen?

This question asks whether it is possible to buy something in Berlin at all (emphasis is on Berlin). A possible answer would be "No, since the great comet strike of 2049, all shops in Berlin are closed".

> Kann ich etwas in Berlin kaufen?

This is a more natural question that might be asked by somebody who is traveling to Berlin and is asking whether (s)he should buy something special there.